# Function to send controller variable to view

Tags: php, function, variables, frameworks, set

For the setting up of a small home framework, I want to send variables to the view, but I have to date find no solutions that works.

The code in question:

**src/Controller/Controller.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;
use App\Network\Request;

class Controller {
    protected $viewPath = ROOT . VIEW;
    protected $template = ROOT . TEMPLATE;
    protected $layout = "default";


    public function __construct()
    {
        $request = new Request();
        $this->render($request->controller().'/'. $request->action());
    }

    public function layout($template) {
        if($template != $this->layout) {
            require $this->template . $template . '.php';
        }
    }

    public function render($view) {

        ob_start();
        require $this->viewPath . '/' . str_replace('.', '/', $view). '.php';
        $content = ob_get_clean();
        require $this->template .$this->layout . '.php';
    }

    public function set($varname) {
        extract($varname);
        return $varname;
    }
}
?>
```

**app/Controller/PostsController.php**

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller;

class PostsController extends Controller {
    public function index() {
        $posts = [
            "id"    => "1",
            "ids"    => "2"
        ];
        $this->set(compact('posts'));
    }
}
?>
```

Using the `$this->set` function in PostsController returns me Undefined variable: posts after an echo.

I also try to put `ob_start` and `ob_get_clean` in the set function but do not work either.

Namely, I do not want to include the function set in render, since I handle the view of the view dynamically (see `__construct ()`).

Another question:

How do I associate a View class with my views and thus use `$this->method ()`.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variables are only limited to function `set` scope. So you cannot see it in render function
Why won't you send array of values into the render function like that

```
public function render($view, array $params = []){
    extract($params, EXTR_OVERWRITE);
    ob_start();
    require $this->viewPath . '/' . str_replace('.', '/', $view). '.php';
    $content = ob_get_clean();
    require $this->template .$this->layout . '.php';
}
```

then you call it like this

```
$this->render('hello', [
    'name' => 'Mikołaj',
    'surname' => 'Woźniak'
]);
```

Comment: Thank you, it works but as I stated in my first post, I would like to avoid calling the view by transmitting a variable.

The ideal would be to retrieve the function you have done me, and replace the view with null, example:
    <?php
    $this->render(null, [
         'Param1' => 'value1',
         'Param2' => 'value2
    ];
    ?>

I try but it does not work, an idea to counter this small problem?

Thank you

Comment: EDIT: I have just managed to modify the function to show that the variables, the variables is displayed well, but still put me a undefined variable ...

See the code: https://code.empreintesduweb.com/11288.html